# Wait on main thread until an asynchronous process is completed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using a proxy which is making asynchronous network calls. The response is to be processed and passed as an argument to the method in the next line. The code illustration is below:

```
- (MyClass *) performOperations{
  ...
  ...
  [self callProxyMethodsTarget:self action:@selector(receivedValue:) withObject:anObject]; //making an asynchronous call here
  return response;
}

- (void) receivedValue:(id)response{     ///need this return value from network call to return from performOperartions
  ...
  ...
}
```

My problem is that as the proxy methods are making asynchronous network calls, I am not able to get the response in time to return it.

I have thought of many things, like:

- making the network calls synchronous but that would require a lot of rework and may introduce unforeseen issues
- changing the return type and pass the response from receivedValue, but can't do that as my client has defined these method names and return types and on other platforms the team is using synchronous calls

I have thought of a solution like:

```
 - (MyClass *) performOperations{
      ...
      ...
      [self callProxyMethodsTarget:self action:@selector(receivedValue:) withObject:anObject]; //making an asynchronous call here

      ///write a code here to wait until response is received
      return response;
    }

    - (void) receivedValue:(id)response{     ///need this return value from network call to return from performOperartions
      ...
      ...
    }
```

But have failed to do so.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that `performOperations` is not called from the main thread, because if it is then you are in trouble. Otherwise you can user the current run-loop like this:

```
- (MyClass *) performOperations{
  _isValueReceived = NO;
  ...
  ...
  [self callProxyMethodsTarget:self action:@selector(receivedValue:) withObject:anObject]; //making an asynchronous call here

  // Start with 10ms time boxes
  NSTimeInterval ti = 0.01;
  // Wait until delegate did callback
  while (!_isValueReceived) {
    NSDate* date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:ti];
    // Let the current run-loop do it's magif for one time-box.
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes
                             beforeDate:date];
    // Double the time box, for next try, max out at 1000ms.
    ti = MIN(1.0, ti * 2);      
  }

  return response;
}

- (void) receivedValue:(id)response {
  ...
  ...
  _isValueReceived = YES;
}
```

This works like a charm for your background threads, and is exactly how GNUStep implements synchronous method dispatches for distributed objects using asynchronous I/O, so should be quite close to how Cocoa does it internally as well.

It is however **not** safe to do on the main thread, since UIKit is not safe for re-entrance into the run loop in the default mode.

Comment: The methods are called from main thread and I can not do much as the library is already built for other platforms and I have to port it for objective-c :(

Comment: There is always something you can do! So the "libarary" is synchronous, live with that, but do not call the "library" from the main thread. Instead of calling `performOperations` directly from the main thread (I am guessing from `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` or similar), just perform an intermediate method on a background thread that do the actual call to `performOperations`.

Comment: I have finally converted the proxy from making asynchronous to synchronous network calls :(

Comment: I was trying to loop through some files retrieved from iCloud. The UIDocument method openWithCompletionHandler runs asynchronously so I used this code to make sure I opened one file at a time, processed it, then moved on to the next file. Then when they all finished being processed, I was able to post a notification and refresh my view. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to slightly refactor your application.  You can't wait where you want to for the result to arrive because that will block the main thread which means that events on the run loop will not be serviced.  This is bad for two reasons

1. the user will experience a locked up application
2. most likely the asynchronous reply is posted to the run loop as an event.  This means you'll never see it and you'll stay blocked forever.

You need to create some state for the application e.g. a flag `proxyRequestMade` and set it when you make the request.  The method would then return to the run loop without returning a value.

Then, when you receive the response, you need to process it and reset the flag.  The reason you have the flag is that it might change the way you handle other UI events e.g. you might disable certain buttons while the request is being made.

Comment: Great answer :) I appreciate it and want to inform you that I was facing the second point you mentioned. Now my condition is worst because I am making a library and need to return the response in real time. May be other developers will use this library in their applications. So I have no other place to wait other then the specified place :( What I have decided is two convert the proxy from making asynchronous to synchronous call now and bring the mammoth down. Anyways thanks for your great information +1 for it.

Answer (score 0):

Do the proxy methods have delegate protocols that indicate their action is complete?

If so -- I don't know your situation, but if you have control of the code then you may be able to add them -- then you can set the calling object as the proxy methods' delegate, call the proxy method at the end of the calling method, and resume when the delegate method was called.

**Edit for sample code**

Your methods can't work quite like they do now because the first one -- the one calling the proxy method -- can't return a value. It might need to have a delegate protocol for whatever's calling it.

```
- (void) performOperations {
  ...
  if (proxyMethod == nil) {
      ProxyMethod *proxyMethod = [[ProxyMethod alloc] init];
  }
  [proxyMethod callProxyMethodsTarget:self action:@selector(receivedValue:) withObject:anObject]; //making an asynchronous call here
}

//Assuming this the the delegate method from the proxy object
- (void) receivedValue:(id)response {   
    // Continue with calling thread here
    // Return information to whatever called performOperations via
    //    a delegate method or a notification
}
```

Comment: Sure the proxy method has delegate method (I have declared the name as) receivedValue: to indicate that the network call is complete. I don't understand what you told in your answer, can you please demonstrate it a little bit with code. You can modify my code as a demo.

Comment: The problem is in the return type my friend. In my code perform operations is returning something but in your code the performOperations is having a void return type :(

Comment: Understood, that's why I put in the comments of `receivedValue` that at that point you will return the value one of two ways. The first option is to add a delegate protocol to the class `performOperations` and `receivedValue` are in, sending the data back to the caller like `[[self perfOpsDelegate] operationSuccessful: YES withResponseValue: response];`. The other option is to use an NSNotificationCenter notification: the caller observes something like ProxyDataUpdatedNotification and `receivedValue` sends that notification with `response` in the notification's `userInfo` dictionary.